# Snakemake cannot write metadata

Tags: windows-10, snakemake

I have troubles to get `snakemake-minimal=7.8.5` to run on Windows 10. I can execute rules, but snakemake terminates due to an error regarding the metadata:

```bash
Failed to set marker file for job started ([Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\test\\project\\.snakemake\\incomplete\\cnVucy9leHBlcmltZW50XzAzL2RmX2ludGVuc2l0aWVzX3Byb3RlaW5Hcm91cHNfbG9uZ18yMDE3XzIwMThfMjAxOV8yMDIwX04wNTAxNV9NMDQ1NDcvUV9FeGFjdGl2ZV9IRl9YX09yYml0cmFwX0V4YWN0aXZlX1Nlcmllc19zbG90XyM2MDcwLzE0X2V4cGVyaW1lbnRfMDNfZGF0YS5pcHluYg=='). Snakemake will work, but cannot ensure that output files are complete in case of a kill signal or power loss. Please ensure write permissions for the directory C:\test\project\.snakemake
```

I tried to troubleshoot doing the following

- change the folders: `Documents`, User folder, and like the above in the root folder of my c drive
- I tried to manipulate the security settings: Controlled folder or RandsomWare Access, see [discussion](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/programs-cant-save-to-documents-folder-briefly-worked-but-then.3461264/) -> it is deactivated

If I erase the `.snakemake` it is re-creating upon execution, so I assume I have write access. However, some security setting is disallowing the long filename with the hash

I tried the same workflow on a different Windows 10 machine and there I don't get the error, so I assume it is some windows issue.

Did anyone encounter the same error and found a solution?

Comment: Random guess: Maybe you are exceeding the maximum length for a filename? Try to manually create the file `C:\test\project\.snakemake\incomplete\cnVucy9l etc etc` to check

Answer (score 2):

I agree it is due to the length of the filename.  It seems the [default max filename length is 260](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry#:%7E:text=which%20is%20defined%20as%20260%20characters).  The file you pasted has a length of 262.  You can [edit the registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later) to allow longer filenames.  Also consider opening an issue in snakemake to improve the documentation or otherwise address this issue for windows machines.

Comment: The full file name is 286 characters long, so could be correct. In one of the latest releases, the length of temporary files was also limited (7.10.0) https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/releases/tag/v7.10.0